# How I can overcome the list view threshold inside our SharePoint online Communication Site document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, list-view-threshold

I am working on a SharePoint Communication modern site, and we have a document library that contains 8,500 files.

Now since the documents are organized inside folders and sub-folders, so we did not face any issues regarding the list view threshold. 
But inside our document library, we have defined 2 managed metadata site columns named (Main Category & Sub Category) and we have the Managed metadata configured on this document library. Today I wanted to group all the documents based on these 2 managed metadata columns, by creating 2 list views. But when I tried to create the first view, and I defined to show all files without folders + group by the managed metadata site column + item limit of 4,500, as follow:-
[image]

I got this error on the modern UI:-

[image]

while if I switch to the classic experience, I will get some results with a warning message as follow:-

[image]

Although as shown inside my above picture I defined the item count inside the list view to be 4500, now I am happy to show only 4500 documents and group them by the "Main Category" managed metadata site column... so can anyone advise on this please? how I can overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we only set Item limit settings in list view, it works as expected in both classic view and modern view. No error and warning in the list view page.

But if we “Group” the items by a column, the list will firstly check if the number of items in this group exceeds list view threshold, if so, it will get the error without executing item limit settings.

So for your issue, make sure that after you set first group, it don't exceeds list view threshold.

Similar issue post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/9cbf81e4-9921-43dd-bd0a-709c243257e8/list-view-threshold-inside-our-sharepoint-online-communication-site-document-library-it-is-showing?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Comment: ok you are correct, as when i removed the group by + i changed the sort from Name to ID i am able to view the 5000 documents...